# What is the best way to initialize an iterator?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

When I started studying C/C++, in my first lessons I learned that we must always declare the variables before using it in our code. So:

```
int iterator = 0; // with optional initialization of value accordingly with its use.

for (iterator = 0 ; ; ) // your loop
```

In this case, we can reuse the same variable `iterator` for as many loops as we want, without need to declare a variable for each loop.

However, I discovered recently that we can also declare and initialize a variable **inside** the `for` loop:

```
for (int iterator = 0 ; ; ) // your loop
```

In this case, the scope of `iterator` is only inside de `for` loop. As it is used as an iterator, and have no other use outside the loop, once it ends, the variable is lost.

Which leads me to question: **what is the best way to initialize an iterator?**¹ Is there a ''best practice'' towards this feature?

¹ = (in terms of most efficient / or resource (RAM) usage / or fastest computation)

Comment: There is no one best way. In general it is best to keep your variables in the narrowest scope possible supporting the second usage. In practice there are reasons why the first would be the best **for that particular code**.

Comment: Best practice for all variables tends to be the closest to where you use it (so you don't have to look all over the place to find it) and in the narrowest possible scope (so it doesn't pollute other parts of the code). So for a loop iterator, put it in the loop unless you need to use the value outside the loop, the final count for example. But rather than iterating like this, can I talk you into using range-based `for` when possible?

Comment: _"In this case, we can reuse the same variable iterator for as many loops as we want, without need to declare a variable for each loop."_ Oof; that's actually the opposite of what you should do!

Comment: Declaring and using built in types (like `int`)on the stack is free so you are not loosing anything by doing the second way and you are gaining safety. So I recommend the second way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¹ = (in terms of most efficient / or resource (RAM) usage / or fastest computation)

Generally, as far as these metrics are concerned, they are equivalent; any modern compiler will statically allocate the stack frame at the function entry and reuse the space across scopes. You can easily see [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5ADdUedAGoAZqlQQ8LAgEoOAZj4AGAIIcTchYoBGTYhG2KOAdiPHF7lSQ1bFeR3oARRUN9Hl9/AGFFWhCDR15%2BPAdnVw80z3Uk0LM3D2cAnJy01TtNAnD9INiwv30o2gBWUPi%2BXiTHFyL091VM3QMu93zCk2KvMorA4ObavSiuapbE5M7R7oyNftS8pwKTYf3zeSUbAC97Du33CbxstZ7x/yqZyOjF/mXLwfTezbvcoa7EYAzylJ7TOKzepNOIfNorK4/NR/Ab3Dp7UxokoacGLKGKBbNOE8dopb5jPr/NIHUy7KTaRjSBpSUgsaSGFmoaQRYmKYRiCTxPS0FkEdn0hkAaxADS4ADpZQA2ACcXEVar0ABZFcLNYypJqWWypBzSFypCzBCBDKQxSb6aQ4LAkGgALYABzwDEwZAoEDdnu9xBAwAAHFxSMovQQfVaIFZxaQrJpbABPaQi0hu12YLQAeRYDHT9tIWFdrGA3sT%2BGImGQBDwMkwVpLmAAHnWRDGMyyypgGImGHgrMQ0xEMJIpJmCMQ8K6ewzmGwUMTGMOrZAGah3Q3UCwWwBaPN6S2icSSWiLplGxPmtuhxUHxWaxTAZDIRShuVcRQQXCEEghXoRRxw9L0fSAhweQSXhRXFbQpRATUnDlZC9EMJw9EwxUGj0RUH31Q1WVvaRLWtW14KvKQuBvEtzTg%2B0ENIJtiEEPA9yQoA%3D%3D) that the code generated for the two functions is exactly the same.

Moreover, integer variables don't require any particular initialization<sup>1</sup>, so it's not like creating new ones at each loop has any cost in runtime.

So, *as a rule of thumb* you should apply the usual rule of keeping each variable to the narrowest required scope, to reduce cognitive load when reading (you know immediately that such variable has only meaning inside that loop, no need to worry about its value being used later, no need to search for it around when you look for its definition) and reduce the risk of bugs (such as not re-initializing it later and reusing its stale value).

---

1. Unlike more complex types, which may invoke costly constructors for each instance; more in general, types used for iterators (be them pointers or STL containers iterator) are cheap to construct.

Answer (score 4):

The word *iterator* has a specific meaning in C++, and this is not what an iterator is. This is usually called a counter or a loop variable.

> (in terms of most efficient / or resource (RAM) usage / or fastest computation)

In the described case, there is practically no difference whatsoever in these terms.

It is usually good design for the scope of a variable to be as small as possible. In this case, that is achieved by declaring the counter within init-statement of the loop. Following this rule-of-thumb often makes it easier for the compiler to minimise memory use, and more importantly, reduces cognitive load of the programmer who needs to grok the algorithm.

There are some algorithms where the final value of the counter is needed after the loop. Such algorithm can be accommodated by hoisting the variable scope out of the scope of the loop.